# Not a supported Play version: 2.7.0. This plugin is compatible with: [PLAY_2_2_X ... PLAY_2_6_X]

Tags: gradle, playframework, sbt

Created a play app using `sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8`. After it was was created I ran the build using 'gradle build'. Then I get the following error:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    ...
    Not a supported Play version: 2.7.0. This plugin is compatible with:
 [PLAY_2_2_X, PLAY_2_3_X, PLAY_2_4_X, PLAY_2_5_X, PLAY_2_6_X]
```

Gradle Version: 4.9

Comment: follow ongoing issues related to this problem https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6362 https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6362